# Prevent linking from an app to my website

Tags: javascript, php, android

Is there any way to prevent linking from an app to my website?
There is an Android app with a lot of advertising that opens my website with the default explorer.
Would it be possible to prevent any link to my website using the app ID?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `default explorer` do you mean `WebView`? It does not pass the app ID to your web site. Technically, the app that opens your web site is a web browser. You may try to ban browsers based on user-agent, but that app developer might just fake the user-agent, so basically there is not way to do that for sure

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny access to your website from an in-app browser, it's basically impossible, but if you want to decide whether to reject it based on the device type. You can try to judge with `UA (User Agent)`, but don't rely on user agent or any type of browser fingerprint, HTTP headers are easy to forge/spoof.

Comment: Just to note - you can set literally any `User-Agent` to the Android `WebView`. So trying to filter by user-agent has nearly no sense

Comment: I know, I also reminded him: 1.  since access from the application's built-in webview, in general, the developer will not modify the system's UA . 2, if the user wants to modify the UA of the independent browser application to access (Assuming the user guesses that UA is a constraint), then the user needs to know the url of the webview's access, but the url is internal to the application and the user cannot know.This is the worst case even if the user can eavesdrop on the interception request and falsify the modification.  It is not meaningless.